# Open a new view when didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In my main view I have a UITableView. I want to open a new view when the user taps on a cell, this is what I have currently:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  WebViewController *web = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
  web.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
  [self presentModalViewController:web animated:YES];
  [web release];
}
```

Problem is, the web view opens 'within' the table view. The table is quite small (320x160px) and so the new web view is only opened within this frame. I need it to open fully/full screen.

I'm guessing the issue is to do with this line:

```
[self presentModalViewController:web animated:YES];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should present not only a `UIWebView` but a `UIViewController` with containing `UIWebView`. I'm guessing from the described behaviour that you NIB contains only a `UIWebView`.

Typically the view controller subclass will include a navigation bar or toolbar so the view can be dismissed.

There a several approaches, but one would be to add a `UIViewController` to your NIB, then drag-in a `UIWebView`, wire-up the outlets etc.,  then your code will work as-is.

Comment: It is a UIViewController, I am just naming it WebViewController.

Comment: Your class name is consistent with it being a controller, which is good. Suspect something is wrond with your NIB construction; you'd need to post more info regarding this.

Comment: Thanks petert, I tried a different approach and it worked. I decided to use NSNotificationCenter as a way to communicate between the two.